# drivers/etc/hosts doesn't work in Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis, hosts-file, etc

the following line in hosts file in windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts doesnt work

```
127.0.0.1 gotomylocal.com
```

I'm using Windows Server 2008, I'm new and configured Windows Server 2008 unconsciously so there might me something like roles or features blocking it.

any idea how can I do that ?

Comment: What does gotomylocal.com resolve to when you ping it? Did you try ipconfig /flushdns ?

Comment: Please rewrite this question to make some actual sense.

Comment: Better still -- don't use HOSTS files. It's 2010... come on...

Comment: `configured Windows Server 2008 unconsciously` - clearly.

Comment: @kyle that didnt work either, ok i edited question for those who doesn't understand easily :P there should be something, modules or sthg blocking this. I just installed Windows Server 2008 R2 and add some features and roles.

Comment: @evan is there any easier way to do this ? though the problem here actually something is blocking the way it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you flushed your DNS cache?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to flush your dns cache.
CMD - Ipconfig -flushdns

then do a CMD ping to the domain name.
Should come up as 127.0.0.1

If that does not do the trick.
make sure your TCP/IP adapter is bound to the 127.0.0.1 ip (it should always be).

If your ping is working fine, then I am assuming you are using a Hosts entry for web development, make sure your IIS Site has host headers for the domain name you placed in your hosts file.